# Напишите программу которая считывает со стандартного ввода целые числа, по одному числу в строке, и после первого введенного нуля заканчивает цикл

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8

Сейчас я изучаю цикл "While" и мне нужно написать программу которая считывает со стандартного ввода целые числа, по одному числу в строке, и после первого введенного нуля заканчивает цикл.Я написал код,который заканчивает цикл если только первая переменная равна нулю,а мне нужно, чтобы цикл заканчивался если последняя переменная равна нулю.

```
a=int(input())
while a!=0:
b=int(input())
if b!=0:
int(input())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = int(input())
while a != 0:
    a = int(input())
```